# merge 2 regular expressions - get the first characters of a hyphenated string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Does anyone know how I can best merge the two `sed` commands in this statement:

```
$ echo "Apple-Boy-Cat" | sed 's/\B.//g;' | sed 's/-//g'
ABC
```

The above works fine but I have a nagging feeling that I am forgetting something that could avoid me running two separate sed statements.

I had tried to do `sed 's/\B.//g;y/-//'` but I get an error of an unterminated `y` command.

Comment: try `sed 's/\B.//g;s/-//g' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the regex alternation operator `\|`.

```
$ echo "Apple-Boy-Cat" | sed 's/\B.\|-//g'
ABC
```

Note that `\B` matches between  two word characters or two non-word characters. It does the opposite of `\b` (*which matches between a word character and a non-word character*).

Comment: Also with `-r` you can write `|` instead of `\|`: `echo "Apple-Boy-Cat" | sed -r 's/\B.|-//g'` (not a big difference but for me at least is easier to read).

Comment: but also consider the systems which has only basic sed. This solution would work for any kind of sed.

Comment: You do not need the `;` at the end, since you only have one command, so: `echo "Apple-Boy-Cat" | sed 's/\B.\|-//g'`

Answer (score 1):

This is not `sed`, but shows how to use `awk` to get same result:

```
echo "Apple-Boy-Cat" | awk -F- '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf substr($i,1,1);print ""}'
ABC
```

It splits the string by `-`, then print the first letter of every word.